# Capture destination page to evaluate what it returns

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

We have a system that allows our parents (I work for a school district) to access district and class resources. It is a third-party product, which is the source of the problem. When a parent logs in, they are actually logging in to a site that I have built. I have to do some checks on their account to see whether they are authorized to pass on to the third-party site. If they are authorized, I simply do an automated form submit with the appropriate login information for the parent.

The problem I'm having is that our vendor doesn't regularly load new data. So, if a student is newly registered at one of our schools, the parent can login and authorize on my side but when I send them to the third-party site, they get an error message indicating no students. I have no way of querying the vendor to see if they will allow the parent in.

What I need to do is run the forms submit to the third party in a "testing" mode that will capture the resulting page in a buffer so I can test the buffer for the error message. If the error message exists, I'll keep them on my side and present them with basic resources. Otherwise, if the error message doesn't exist, I need to do the actual form submit and allow the browser to re-direct. Possibly an AJAX solution? The following is the existing code:

ASPX page (yes, I have the appropriate headers, etc., this is the relevant code):

```
<form method="post" name="loginform" action="http://[destination page]" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<% =SessionHandler.UserEmail %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<% =SessionHandler.UserPassword %>" />
    <%--<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />--%>
</form>
```

Javascript (that executes the form submit):

```
function parentFormSubmit() {
    document.loginform.submit();
}
```

VB Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
    Session.Abandon()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "parentFormSubmit();", True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the way you can accomplish this is by doing a manual HTTPPost by either using a Socket or the `WebRequest` class.

[Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

[Sockets](http://socketprogramming.blogspot.com/)

I would use the WebRequest class because it is easier and faster and you could find tons of samples online.

Good luck!

Comment: We're close but not quite there. I found an [example here](http://www.808.dk/?code-vbnet-httpwebrequest) that is working, sort of. The URI I'm passing in is the vendor's login form. It appears the form data (username/password) is being sent but the "submit" for the login form is not getting "clicked" so what gets returned is the actual vendor login page rather than the login result, which is what I need. Any ideas what the sample is doing wrong? I can't find anything else that looked different.

Comment: Have you done any package analysis using a Sniffer? You should try it out so that you see exactly what is going on. Maybe it does a redirect once the form is submitted, or maybe it is the same login page with a hidden div with the desired result. I wish I could help you more, but I can't without the actual page.

Comment: Well, I didn't use a Sniffer but I was able to figure out what was going on. Ultimately, your solution of using the WebRequest Class has solved the issue. I tried to give you credit but it wouldn't let me vote on your answer since I'm too new of a user to this forum. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent! I am glad. You can still mark as the answer even though you can't give me credit. Good luck!